# gradient of Listview items doesnot change ontapping

Tags: java, android, listview, gradient

I have a listview settup using an custom array adapter the list appears fine I have used an gradient ans the background of each item which also appears but the code also states to change gradient on tapping which doesnot occur  below are my xml's

**main.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

     />
```

**row_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtListText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:background="@drawable/ogbg" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->

<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ogbg" />

   <item android:state_pressed="true"  
        android:drawable="@drawable/ogpress" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
       android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ogpress" />

</selector>
```

**ogbg.xml// normal background gradient**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient 
android:startColor="#FFFAFAFA" 
android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

**ogpress.xml//gradient to change on tapping**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   

android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient 
android:startColor="#FF05c1ff" 
android:endColor="#7F05c1ff" 
android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past. Try to switch the order of your selector items, I don´t know why, but the behavior of a selector depends on the order of items. If this doesn´t work, try to deparate "selected" and "pressed". Do an extra item for every state.